# ObjectiveDDP and meteor update/Insert Collection

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, meteor

I'm developing an simple app that shows messages and comments.. I need to Update the messages by adding new comments.
I create a json that inserts messages and comments.. the comments are part of the message it's an array..

```
{    
   "text": "Message Text!!!",    
   "createdAt": "new Date()",    
   "comments": [    
      {    
         "text": "Comment One",    
         "createdAt": ""    
      },

      {    
         "text": "Comment Two",    
         "createdAt": ""    
      }    
   ]    
}
```

From client side I need to add a new comment (a new item in the comment array), but I'm really new on this library and no sure how to invoke this method to update..

```
    NSArray *parameters = @[@{@"_id": self.message.messageId},                            
                   @{@"$set":@{@"Comments":@{@"text":@"newComment"}}}];

   [self.meteor callMethodName:@"/Messages/update" parameters:parameters responseCallback:nil];
```

This adds a new item in the json comments, but not as a part of the array.

Thanks in advance!

i'm using this [lib](https://github.com/boundsj/ObjectiveDDP)
to set mi meteor IOS app as a client of the meteor server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mongo syntax problem. You need to use `$push` instead of `$set` to add the element to the array. See the mongo documentation at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Try:

```
NSArray *parameters = @[@{@"_id": self.message.messageId},                            
               @{@"$push":@{@"Comments":@{@"text":@"newComment"}}}];
```